# Generate SAS token to manage Azure Blob Container using PowerShell REST API

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, rest

*I'm downloading files from Azure Blob Storage with PowerShell REST API*. The code works perfectly, the only think is that I have to hardcode the SAS. Instead of hardcoding the SAS I want to generate the SAS token programmatically in **PowerShell REST API**.
This is the reference of the code I'm using https://rzander.azurewebsites.net/download-files-from-azure-blob-storage-with-powershell/

I searched lot of documentation on Microsoft Doc, I found one for Azure Event Hub  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#powershell

I am looking for some thing similar to this which can generate the SAS for *Azure Storage Account*, *Azure Blob Container* but it should be the in **PowerShell REST API**.

Note: I cannot use **Az** cmdlet module `New-AzStorageAccountSASToken` because I am implementing this in Azure Function App Trigger, and I need to use simple REST API in PowerShell.

---

**Update**: I tried to use the documentation to generate the SAS Token. Below is the PowerShell REST API code:

```
Function Get-MyBlob{
        $StorageAccountName = "MYSTORAGEACCOUNT"
        $StorageContainerName = "MYCONTAINER"
        $StorageAccountKey = "MYSTORAGEACCOUNTACCESSKEY"
        $blobItem = "coloured-paper.jpg"
        $Url = "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$StorageContainerName/$blobItem"

        $signedPermissions = "rw"
        $signedStart = "2021-10-03"
        $signedExpiry = "2021-10-13"
        $canonicalizedResource = "/$StorageAccountName/$StorageContainerName/$blobItem"
        $signedVersion = "2012-02-12"

        $StringToSign = $signedpermissions + "\n" +  
               $signedstart + "\n" +  
               $signedexpiry + "\n" +  
               $canonicalizedresource + "\n" +
               $signedVersion + "\n"
        

        $sharedKey = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($StorageAccountKey)

        $hasher = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
        $hasher.Key = $sharedKey              
        $signedSignature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hasher.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($StringToSign)))

        $method = "GET"
        $headerDate = '2012-02-12'
        $headers = @{"x-ms-version" = "$headerDate" }
        $xmsdate = (get-date -format r).ToString()
        $headers.Add("x-ms-date", $xmsdate)
        
        $headers.Add("Authorization", "SharedKey " + $StorageAccountName + ":" + $signedSignature);
        write-host -fore green $signatureString
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method $method -headers $headers
    }
```

But when I invoke this, I get following error:

```
Error Details: AuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request. Make sure 
the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:47e97e15-601e-0068-202d-b9caad000000
Time:2021-10-04T14:40:11.3025359ZThe MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'JQ54my0pZGv+XpcaMMiVjXOXV/e0ATU1TrWewgqU4Gs=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET
0
x-ms-date:Mon, 04 Oct 2021 20:10:09 GMT
x-ms-version:2012-02-12
/mkatestscriptstorage/usl-customer-package/coloured-paper.jpg'.
```

Can anyone help what error am I making. Is the `StringToSign` valid?

Comment: As such there's no REST API for generating SAS token. You would simply have to follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#constructing-the-signature-string) and write equivalent PowerShell code.

Comment: I'm novice in PowerShell, I was hoping if anyone can help me.

Comment: You can refer this to create a service sas as stated by Gaurav Mantri : https://www.example-code.com/powershell/azure_create_service_sas.asp

Comment: I've updated the question with my PowerShell code but it is throwing error. Can anyone help. Thanks!